# Times-Square and today's date

Tags: android, calendar, widget, android-time-square

Quick question to users of Square's Times-Square calendar widget.  Is there any way NOT to have it highlight's today's date?

Currently, it highlights today's date with a dark grey and I would like to disable that.  I have looked at the GitHub code and could not figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

To change the background colour of todays date you need to override calendar_bg_selector.xml in your drawable folder and change:

`<item app:tsquare_state_today="true">
    <color android:color="@color/new_bg_colour"/>
 </item>`

Similarly to change the text colour of todays date override calendar_text_selector.xml in your res/color package and change:

```
<item app:tsquare_state_today="true" android:color="@color/new_text_colour"/>
```

Original files at gitHub:

https://github.com/square/android-times-square/blob/master/library/src/main/res/color/calendar_text_selector.xml

https://github.com/square/android-times-square/blob/master/library/src/main/res/drawable/calendar_bg_selector.xml

Answer (score -1):

```
calendar.init(today, maxDate.getTime());//.withSelectedDate(today); remove this
```